# infopath 2010 submit to document library map field value to a submitted item column

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I created a form in infopath 2010 which is submitted to a sharepoint 2010 document library
I Have a field in the infopath form called "day" and I need to map it to a column named "day" in the document library when the form submitted.

Please any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Form Options -> Promoted Properties -> Add